# Laravel BrowserSync without proxy

Tags: php, laravel, browser-sync

I'm trying to use Elixir BrowserSync, one of the newest features of Laravel.

I added it to the gulp file

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
    .browserSync();
});
```

when I run "gulp watch" it output this message

```
[20:49:20] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/laravel/gulpfile.js
[20:49:20] Starting 'watch'...
[20:49:20] Finished 'watch' after 11 ms
[BS] Proxying: http://homestead.app
[BS] Access URLs:
----------------------------------
Local: http://localhost:3000
External: http://10.9.0.48:3000
```

Automatically a browser is launched with the url http://localhost:3000 but nothing loads.

I think the problem is related to this line:
    [BS] Proxying: http://homestead.app

Comment: We cannot see the line in the file. That last url you included is broken; instead make a fiddle or include the relevent pieces here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running multiple homestead sites? It looks like it defaults to proxying through homestead.app if you do not include a proxy setting. If you don't host your local on homestead.app it won't find it.

Try

.browserSync({ proxy: 'domain.app' });

Where domain.app is what you are serving the site with.

Comment: Yes, its the problem. I want it to not use a proxy. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think so unfortunately. It looks like it is dependant on it.

Comment: @koorb solution works, just disable the proxy setting and specify a path to serve the files from (i.e. "./public" or something), i think that should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can if you use BrowserSyncs server.

```js
mix.browserSync({
  proxy: false,
  server: {
    baseDir: './'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer to your question - it is not possible to not proxy the `.browserSync`. Long side-answer - you can still use elixir's implementation of `browserSync` in `gulp`, but you must have a separate PHP server to interpret the files.

---

**Edit:** I saw a way to not proxy by providing the script in the pages manually (by not giving any arguments in the `.browserSync()` call, but don't remember where and how to do it exactly.

---

The reason is that browserSync requests all the data from the server for you, injects a little javascript listener and displays everything else:

```
<script type='text/javascript' id="__bs_script__">//<![CDATA[document.write("<script async src='/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.2.9.11.js'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));//]]></script>
```

One way is to `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0` in a separate terminal to start up the server and then use the `.browserSync({proxy: 'localhost:8000'})`. It all works - the BrowserSync UI and all the calls to refresh the pages.

**Note:** I could not connect to `artisan serve` without the `--host=0.0.0.0`.

---

For those wanting an all automated solution via `gulp`, here it is:

Use  the gulp packages `gulp-connect-php` and `laravel-elixir-browsersync2`. The first starts up the `php artisan serve` and the other connects it to `browserSync`.

1. Install the packages:

   - `npm install laravel-elixir-browsersync2 --save-dev`
   - `npm install gulp-connect-php --save-dev`
2. Add the required lines to your `gulpfile.js`:

Code:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir'),
    gulp = require('gulp');
var connectPHP = require('gulp-connect-php');
var BrowserSync = require('laravel-elixir-browsersync2');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
});

elixir(function(mix) {
    connectPHP.server({
        base: './public',
        hostname: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 8000
    });
    BrowserSync.init();
    mix.BrowserSync(
    {
        proxy: 'localhost:8000',
        logPrefix       : "Laravel Eixir BrowserSync",
        logConnections  : false,
        reloadOnRestart : false,
        notify          : false
    });
});
```

3. Then - simply `gulp`.

**Disclaimer:** This might not work with the `gulp watch`, but there might be people with the answer to that.

There is also a line `PHP server not started. Retrying...` before the `[Laravel Eixir BrowserSync] Proxying: http://localhost:8000`. It belongs to `gulp-connect-php` when trying to check if the server is running.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. Thank you. On a side note, `gulp watch` seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found other solution on laracast for Bloomanity and it works with me like a charm!
`$ php artisan serve --host=0`
and then in your gulp add:
`mix.browserSync({proxy: 'localhost:8000'});`